# ./eagle executes, however `bash eagle` does not

Tags: bash, bashrc

Upon downloading Eagle 7.6, I wanted to add an alias to it. Even though `./eagle` opens the application, `bash eagle` results `cannot execute binary file` error. I tried `chmod +x eagle` but it didn't help. Downloaded version is the 64 bit version.

The alias I created is as follows:

```
alias eagle='bash /home/metin/eagle-7.6.0/bin/eagle'
```

In case you wonder, here is the `uname -a` output:

```
Linux mettinoktay 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC
2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like `eagle` is a binary rather than a script, so running `bash eagle` doesn't make sense

Comment: yup it doesnt make any sense as `./eagle` is more comfortable than to type `bash eagle`

Comment: What do you mean by "add an alias" to it and why do you think `bash eagle` would help?

Comment: By "add an alias", I mean that I'm trying to launch Eagle from terminal like I'm doing with dRonin and sage (check the .bashrc file screenshot).

Comment: And because `bash drgcs` and `bash sage` helped, I thought `bash eagle` would also help.

Comment: Remove `bash` from your alias

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's because `eagle` is a compiled executable, not a bash script. You are getting confused because you often see `bash ./script` suggested as a way of running the bash script saved in the text file `script`. For example:

```
$ cat foo.sh
echo "hello!"
$ bash ./foo.sh
hello!
```

So, the command `bash ./foo.sh` actually means "run `bash` and ask it to execute the commands found in the file `foo.sh`". However, binary executables are not shell scripts, they are not a list of simple commands and cannot be run that way. For example, if you try to run the `ls` binary using `bash`:

```
$ bash /bin/ls
/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

That's `bash` telling you it can't run this thing you told it to run because it is a binary file and not a text file containing a script.

So, to fix your problem, just remove the `bash` from your alias and, instead, point it to the actual location of the `eagle` executable:

```
alias eagle='/home/metin/eagle-7.6.0/bin/eagle'
```

Alternatively, add `/home/metin/eagle-7.6.0/bin/` to your `$PATH` by adding this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/metin/eagle-7.6.0/bin/"
```

That will let you execute any executable files in `/home/metin/eagle-7.6.0/bin/` by name (by running `eagle` in this case) just like you do with any other executables such as `bash` itself, or `ls`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive answer. It was like a tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

`bash` has to be removed from alias, that is:

```
alias eagle='/home/metin/eagle-7.6.0/bin/eagle'
```

@doug solved this issue on comments.